# Ler linha por linha de TXT e retornar ao finalizar (PHP)

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function pegarWS($numero){

    $PEGAR_WS = 'http://ws.com.br';
    $URL = $PEGAR_WS.$numero;

$proxies = file('pasta/secreta/inacessivel/via/http/proxies.txt');

//Limpa espaços em branco
$proxies = array_map(function ($proxy) {
    return trim($proxy);
}, $proxies);

// pegar random proxy


 $proxy_to_use = $proxies[ rand( 0, count( $proxies ) -1 ];

foo
```

Essa parte em especial: (preciso adaptar)

```
$proxy_to_use = $proxies[ rand( 0, count( $proxies ) -1 ];
```

No lugar de buscar o proxy de forma random (vide código), eu preciso alterar para que ele leia linha por linha do txt (uma por vez) em loop. Ou seja, leia a primeira linha, depois a segunda e assim por diante.. Quando chegar na última linha ele volta para a primeira.

Comment: Não ficou claro o que precisa nem que erro está a obter

Comment: @JorgeCosta, deixei a pergunta mais detalhada.

Comment: Porque não coloca o código dentro do array_map ?

Comment: @JorgeCosta, eu travei onde está na pergunta :-( Não consigo ler linha por linha.

Comment: Para ver se eu percebi de cada vez que invocar pegarWS você quer devolver uma linha do ficheiro de forma sequencial

Comment: @JorgeCosta, exato.

Comment: Aí você vai ter que manter um índice da última linha utilizada e talvez também o array das linhas para não estar sempre a ler o ficheiro (melhor desempenho)

Comment: Mas você quer recuperar essas linhas dentro do arquivo? Ou cada vez que você chama a função ela retorna uma linha em específico?

Comment: @AndreiCoelho, cada vez que ele abre o arquivo, ele retorna a próxima linha e quando chegar na ultima linha, ele volta para a primeira.

Comment: Tinha feito a pergunta errada. O que eu queria saber é se você quer recuperar essas linhas dentro da função ou se cada vez que chama a função ele retorna a linha... Mas acredito que é a segunda opção.

Comment: Era isso? Recuperar linha por linha a cada chamada de função?

Comment: É exatamente isso. Só não estou conseguindo colocar no meu código...

Comment: Tem um outra opção.. Vou postar para você.

Comment: Tenta a opção usando sessão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito, você pode usar recursividade para fazer isso. Desta forma ele irá retornar sempre a próxima linha e voltará para a primeira sempre que arquivo chegar ao fim. O limite é o `for`.

```
function pegarWS($numero){

  $file = file("pasta/secreta/inacessivel/via/http/proxies.txt"); 
  if(isset($file[$numero])){
      return $file[$numero];
  }
  // se não existir o índice subtrai o número
  // envia para a mesma função até chegar ao índice 0
  return pegarWS ($numero - count($file));

}

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    echo pegarWS($i);
}
```

**Uma sugestão**

Abrir o arquivo apenas uma vez.

```
$file = file("pasta/secreta/inacessivel/via/http/proxies.txt"); 
$linhas = [];
foreach($file as $linha){
    $linhas[] = $linha;
}

$y = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    if(!isset($linhas[$y])){
        $y = 0;
    } 
    echo $linhas[$y];
    $y++;
}
```

**Outra opção**

Usando sessão para guardar os índices

```
function pegarWS($numero){

    $PEGAR_WS = 'http://ws.com.br';
    $URL = $PEGAR_WS.$numero;

    $proxies = file('pasta/secreta/inacessivel/via/http/proxies.txt');

    //Limpa espaços em branco
    $proxies = array_map(function ($proxy) {
        return trim($proxy);
    }, $proxies);

    if(!isset($_SESSION['index'])){
        $index = $_SESSION['index'] = 0;
    } else {
        $index = $_SESSION['index'];
    }
    if(isset($proxies[$index])){
        $linha = $proxies[$index];
    } else {
        $linha = $proxies[0];
        $_SESSION['index'] = 0;
    }
    $_SESSION['index']++;

    $proxy_to_use = $linha;

    // ... resto do código
}
```

Comment: ~ Certinho! Obrigado!

Comment: @J.Doe tranquilo!